A probably Japanese animated TV series in which a person of royal blood must pretend to be a member of the opposite sex
Identify this animated series, My recollection may not be 100% accurate.
Premise: A person of royal blood must pretend to be a person of the opposite sex on pain of some political disaster. (Not sure whether it was a male pretending to be female or the other way around.)
Category: Animated T.V. series for children.
Country of production: Probably, Japan.
Production date: 1970s or earlier.
Setting: What looks like a European country. The characters are wearing Jane Eyre or Three Musketeer type attire.
Hero/Heroine: A teenager or young adult.
Motifs:

A pen of truth.  With it you can only write the truth.  Therefore the protagonist must not use it.
A love interest of sorts, a male character.  So either our "prince," while ostensibly friends with him, is actually in love; or our "princess," while ostensibly the object of that other character's love, cannot respond.


Is it Princess Knight?

Princess Knight is the story of young Princess Sapphire who must pretend to be a male prince so she can inherit the throne as women are not eligible to do so. As she is born, her father, the King, announces his baby is a boy instead of a girl. The reason for this is that the next-in-line to the throne, Duke Duralumin is an evil man who would repress the people if his son were to become king.


She even have a love interest Prince Franz Charming. 
